# getId returns empty string in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have made a CRUD for my question object. An error occurred once I tested it.

It seems that the getId() is returning an empty string of some sort.

The default behavior of the autogenerated CRUD is to redirect the user to the view page after successfully creating the entity. But in this case, it returns an error

"**Parameter "id" for route "question_show" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.**"

Here is my controller code:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Question entity.
 *
 * @Route("/ask", name="question_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("VerySoftAskMeBundle:Question:ask.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Question();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('question_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }


    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

Here is the view action:

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Question entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="question_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('VerySoftAskMeBundle:Question')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Question entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
/**
 * Creates a form to create a Question entity.
 *
 * @param Question $entity The entity
 *
 * @return Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Question $entity) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('question_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'em' => $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Ask'));

    return $form;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: is your object inserted into DB?

Comment: The object is inserted but this error occurs everytime I get redirected to the view page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your entity is not persisted in the database. Could you check it?

Also, it seems to be a typo in your code your wrote "$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);", instead of $this->createForm

Otherwise I have used the code below (similar to yours) with no problem

```
/**
 * @Route("/new", name="item_new")
 * @Template()
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $item = new Item();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemType(), $item, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('item_new'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($item);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('item_list'));
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Comment: It's not a typo. I really do have that method.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I was inheriting a class named `Post` which has an `$id` variable. Turns out that I forgot to delete the `$id` variable in my `Question` class which is why Symfony gets confused on what id to return.